# tsc --build + specify tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript

I want to run

```
tsc --build
```

But I want to have tsc use a different tsconfig.json file.

```
npx tsc --build --project tsconfig-abc.json
```

But I get this error

```
error TS5094: Compiler option '--project' may not be used with '--build'.
```

I've tried adding the build option to tsconfig but that doesn't seem to work?

```
  "buildOptions": {
    "build" : true
  },
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is simply to provide the file name at the end - no param name.

```
tsc --build tsconfig-simple.json
```

Comment: tsc --build --clean tsconfig-simple.json is not working any other similar?

Comment: tsc --build tsconfig-simple.json --clean

Comment: I cannot get it to work: it doesn't build project references

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
> tsc -p ./path/to/tsconfig.json
```

Compiles the TypeScript project located at the specified path.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work with the --build flag